# python multiprocessing - single file multiple commands

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've a requirement of processing a file which contains some 100 shell (bash) commands; each line has a separate shell command. I have to execute these commands parallely (like 10 commands in parallel or 20, let the CPU decide how to do that in parallel). I honestly don't know how to accomplish it so I took a code somewhere around here only; below is the same:

```
from subprocess import PIPE
import subprocess
import time


def submit_job_max_len(job_list, max_processes):
  sleep_time = 0.1
  processes = list()
  for command in job_list:
    print 'running process# {n}. Submitting {proc}.'.format(n=len(processes),
        proc=str(command))
    processes.append(subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, stdout=None, stdin=PIPE))
    while len(processes) >= max_processes:
      time.sleep(sleep_time)
      processes = [proc for proc in processes if proc.poll() is None]
  while len(processes) > 0:
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    processes = [proc for proc in processes if proc.poll() is None]


cmd = 'cat runCommands.sh'
job_list = ((cmd.format(n=i)).split() for i in range(5))
submit_job_max_len(job_list, max_processes=10)
```

I don't understand the last 3 lines as to what actually it's doing. My test runs show that the number in `range(n)` will execute ever line that many times. So if the number is 5, then every line is executed 5 times. I don't want that. Can someone throw some light on this please. And again, please excuse my ignorance here.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel is made for you:

```
cat the_file | parallel
```

By default it will run one job per cpu-core. This can be adjusted with `--jobs`.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons you should install GNU Parallel with your package manager, but if GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: Thanks Ole. As much as this looks appealing(gnu fan btw) , I won't be able to use this solution for the query here. But thanks for bringing this here. Upping the answer anyways.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you will not be able to use the solution? Is it covered by http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html

Comment: To use it, I'll have to have GNU parallel package present on the cluster. Which last time I checked wasn't present. My administrator won't allow the installation unless it's a proven case to them.

Comment: But you are allowed to run your own scripts? As mentioned on oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html you do not need root to do a personal installation. Also `--embed` (from 20180222) may be useful to you.

Comment: No mate, not even Internet connection. But I did try on my local. Does the job but yeah, the actual parallelism I couldn't reckon there.

Comment: "No mate" Does that mean that you are not even allowed to run the script you have written above? Because if you are not allowed to run your own scripts, then I think that is a restriction you really need to mention in the problem. And if you *are* allowed to run your own scripts, why does `parallel --embed` not work for you?

Comment: I meant wget the parallel package on the first hand from outside. Not the execution of the script.

Comment: @knowone Can you elaborate on whether `parallel --embed` (version 20180222 and later) will work for you? By embedding GNU Parallel into your script you do not need internet access, but can just run your script.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a queue.

Use the multiprocessing package to start a set of processes. There are several examples which show how to do this.

One neat trick is to use a poison pill to ensure each of the processes is killed once the queue is empty. Search the python module of the week for examples on this.

Best of luck.